# Android - How to change EditText line color with animation like Google Forms?

Tags: android, android-edittext, google-forms

I am trying to achieve an animation similar to google forms as shown in the gif below:
[image]

The bottom line of EditText should change color with fill animation starting from the center. 
It might be easy but I am new to android and I didn't find any online resource for this problem. Can anybody just give me a slight hint or provide a link to some tutorial on how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this [blog](http://blog.rowburst.com/229/change-edittext-line-color-with-animation/). The blog implements a workaround for exactly the same animation you want to achieve. You can achieve this by setting the background of your **EditText** to `#00000000` and using two **Views** in **FrameLayout** (One on top of another, the top one being invisible at first) as bottom line of **EditText**. When **EditText** gains focus then you can make the **View** (one on the top) visible and add scale animation to the **View** to achieve similar effect.

Comment: The link is down. Please refer a valid link.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, here is github repo [link](https://github.com/GitHub-Tech/EditText-Line-Animation)

Comment: @QandeelAbbasi you can also update the answer link as well!!

Comment: The blog is no longer functional. I have given github repo link above. If you need any help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

I think google does it with `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal`.

Here is how I achieved this effect (note it is for api 21 and above)

Also note that I use touch point for better UX

so we need following:
**selector_line_bellow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="-25dp">
                <shape android:shape="line">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                    <stroke
                        android:width="3dp"
                        android:color="#017ba7"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <!-- default-->
    <item >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="-25dp">
                <shape android:shape="line">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                    <stroke
                        android:width="3dp"
                        android:color="#11017ba7"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </item>
</selector>
```

our `EditText` will look like this

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_line_bellow"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and last touch is in your activity class or wherever this `EditText` will be used add this piece of code

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(editText,
                        (int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY(),
                        0,
                        editText.getHeight() * 2).start();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something that looks like, I would put it under your TextView:

```
package com.example.trist_000.teststack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class customm extends View {



private class myanim extends Animation{

    public myanim(){
        this.setRepeatMode(INFINITE);
        this.setRepeatCount(INFINITE);
        this.setDuration(2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        time =(getWidth()/2)*interpolatedTime;
        postInvalidate();
    }
}

public customm(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public customm(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    myanim anim = new myanim();
    this.startAnimation(anim);

}

Paint paint = new Paint();
float time = 0;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight()/2, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight()/2, (getWidth()/2)-time, getHeight()/2, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / 2,getHeight()/2, (getWidth()/2) +time, getHeight()/2, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

In your xml file:

```
<com.example.trist_000.teststack.customm
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />
```

You have to improve it a little bit ;).